# How can I work with a file in ruby without moving it into memory?

Tags: ruby, file, filesystems

I need to work with a massive file that won't fit into memory, or even if it does, I don't need it all in memory because I only need to seek to and modify a certain portion of it.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Can you break it into modules? Several files?

Comment: For the sake of argument, assume no, because yes would defeat the point of this interesting question.

Comment: Yes. Nobody says you must read **the entire** file into memory. There is standard streaming (only input/ouput as needed), random-access (seek to read records) as well as mmap (similar to standard seek model). Of course, some operations -- e.g. adding or deleting to the front -- can be more complicated.

Comment: -1 Which documentation did you find on seeking? What currently has been tried? You know the keywords. Try and use them. If it is more an architectural issue -- e.g. how can I work with format X or do operation Y -- then rewrite the question in those terms.

Comment: Is there something in the [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html) or [IO](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) documentation that you're having trouble with?

Comment: @muistooshort indeed, the docs do not (explicitly?) describe this aspect of behavior for `IO` and its descendants.

Comment: Searching for "seek" would have gotten you to `sysseek` and that probably would have led to `sysread` and `syswrite`.

Comment: The word "memory" is nowhere in this document http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of tweaking the middle of a sort-of-large file without reading any of it at all into memory. But if you wanted to read just a little, see [IO.sysread.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-sysread)

```
TestFile = '/tmp/test'
system "cp /usr/share/dict/words #{TestFile}; chmod +w #{TestFile}"

File.open TestFile, 'r+' do |io|
  io.sysseek 1000000
  io.syswrite 'EASTER EGG!!!'
end
system "grep EASTER.EGG #{TestFile}"
```

sysread and syswrite are useful for several situations:

- You are doing a single I/O op or various I/O ops at different places (buffering won't help)
- You are doing large I/O ops (buffering will be slightly slower)
- Your program is sophisticated or just generally block-oriented and is doing its own buffering

Comment: thanks. hmm, I can't tell the difference between `#seek` and `#sysseek` from the docs... do you know what it is?